# Running Akka Application on a Server/Container

Tags: akka, akka-http

I am new to Akka Framework and I am doing a POC on it.

Using Akka Http, I am trying to resolve a Http Request and return a response. But my query is how could we run this Akka application in a server environment. All the examples I could see is as look below.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  ActorSystem system = ActorSystem.create("userServer");
  ActorRef userActor = system.actorOf(UserActor.props(), "userActor");
  UserServer server = new UserServer(userActor);
  server.startServer("localhost", 8080, system);
}
```

As per my understanding, this is we are running the application from a standalone file. But in an enterprise version we always intended to run an application through a Server.

So How possibly we could run the Akka application through server?

Comment: Even in production settings, you usually use `server.startServer("localhost", 8080, system)`, or `0.0.0.0`, or such. Works well inside containers, too, if you know what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

It’s not clear what you mean by “through server”. Do you mean a JEE server? There’s no need or benefit of doing anything like that.

Running in a production server or container typically just involves running from a command line the same way you are doing now. There are tools in both maven and sbt (and others) to help you with the details of packaging and containerizing.